# visualising changes in a distribution over time

Tags: javascript, visualization, data-visualization, plotly

I have a distribution of numbers given as a list of numbers, with duplicates allowed, such as [0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5].

This distribution changes over time. Each distribution may have a different number of elements, but should usually be similarly sized

I am trying to visualise this change of distributions in Javascript, but can't find a satisfactory solution. I am using plotly for other visualisations already, so a solution in plotly would be preferred, but is not required.

My current approach is to make a scatterplot with heatmap, and enter data points by giving each new distriubtion a new sequentially generated x coordinate, while treating the entries of the distribution as y coordinates. This works reasonably well when the sequentially generated number is small compared to the number in the distribution, but looks odd otherwise, because I don't know how to tell the scatterplot that the x coordinate is artificial and there can never be a data point between two subsequent x coordinates.

For extra credit, find a way to visualise it nicely even if the distributions can be based on a vastly different number of elements.

Comment: You need something like `geom_density` from `ggplot2`- but this is only available in R.  Might help your search though to read up about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a standard solution in Javascript, but I found a way around:

I show a graph with 11 lines. Each line is a 10% quantile of the distribution I am tracking. It's a bit unintuitive at first, but very informative once you are used to it.